# Cross Correlation of a template over multiplie images

Tags: matlab

I have written a code that performs the cross correlation of a template over multiple images in matlab.This code is meant to track the movement of a cell across multiple frames, the code is somewhat interactive, first the user selects the image template from the first frame than he/she runs the program to perform the cross correlation, I have define a region of interest where the code has to find this template. My question how do I obtain the x and y coordinates of the position of the cells after the cross correlation has detected and located it across all the frames

```
 format long
fontSize = 10;
file_name = 'stack0001.tif';  %TIFF Stack
image_info = imfinfo(file_name);
numImg = length(image_info) %Number of images in stack
rgbImage = imread(file_name,'Index', 1);
[sub_rgbImage,rect_rgbImage] = imcrop(rgbImage);
figure,
imshow(sub_rgbImage)
title({'Template Image ' ;'to Search For'});
h=figure;
 for i1=1:numImg %Read Each Frame
    fprintf('Now correlating frame #%d with frame #%d\n',1,i1);

    rect_A= [247.5 134.5 35 81]; % region to look for object
    A=imread(file_name,'Index', i1);%read the following image from image loop (in tiff stack)
    sub_A = imcrop(A,rect_A); % Region of Interest
    figure,
    imshow(sub_A); % Show region of Interest
    axis on;

    % Search the red channel for a match.
    correlationOutput = normxcorr2(sub_rgbImage(:,:,1), sub_A(:,:,1));
    x=size(correlationOutput, 2);
    y=size(correlationOutput, 1);
    h=figure;
    set(h,'visible','off');
    figure, surf(correlationOutput),shading flat;


    h=figure;
    set(h,'visible','off');
    figure('Position', [300 300 300 300]);
    imshow(correlationOutput, []);
    sprintf('Normalized Cross Correlation Output of frame #%d and #%d\n',i1,i1+1);
    title('Cross Correlation');
    %Offset between the images found by correlation

    [maxCorrValue, maxIndex] = max(abs(correlationOutput(:)))
    [ypeak,xpeak] = ind2sub(size(correlationOutput),maxIndex(1))
    corr_offset = [(ypeak-size(sub_rgbImage,1)) 
                       (xpeak-size(sub_rgbImage,2))] ;


    %relative offset between position of subimages
    rect_offset = [(rect_A(1)- rect_rgbImage(1))
                   (rect_A(2)- rect_rgbImage(2))]

    %total offset
    offset = rect_offset+corr_offset;
    xoffset= offset(1)
    yoffset= offset(2)


end
```

Comment: Looks like you've already done the calculation. Just use your offset values to move the object. If this is not what you're after then you're going to have to make your question a bit more detailed (less code, more explanation of what you want/what is wrong with the code).

Comment: Ok Thank you for your reply. I have a stack of images that captures the movement of a cell as it moves (this movement is of the order of nanometer). Now I would like to obtain the x and y coordinate of the cell's position in each frame. Another way to say this is that, I want the x&y coordinates in frame1,frame2 etc (where each frame captures the cell at a different position).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the boundaries if you can convert it to a binary image. Perhaps by thresholding the background and creating a binary image of your cell. Then you can use regionprops methods to access properties of the connected components in the image. Or you can use bwboundaries and know the outline pixels identities rather than a centroid.